# Autofac, WebAPI, and Media Formatters

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

I need some assistance.  I am trying to use Autofac to get me a few dependencies that are need for a custom media formatter.  I followed the Wiki but it is a little confusing.  I am trying to use property injection for the media formatter since it needs to be registered with the global configuration.

Code:

```
public class UserMediaFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public UsersRepository repository { get; set; }
}

 public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
 {
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(2, new UserMediaFormatter());
    builder.RegisterType(typeof(UserMediaFormatter)).PropertiesAutowired()
               .As<MediaTypeFormatter>()
               .InstancePerApiControllerType(typeof (UsersController));

 }

 [AutofacControllerConfiguration]
 public class UsersController : ApiController
 {
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to use your `UserMediaFormatter` globally in all of your controller? Because the `InstancePerApiControllerType` only registers it for the `UsersController` or this is what you would like to have anyway?

Comment: That is what I would like to have happen, but for some reason it does not appear to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let Autofac to add your custom formatter to the marked controllers then you don't need to add it to the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters` because it makes your formatter globally available and it prevents Autofac to inject properties on it.

So remove the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert` call

and use the following exact syntax to register your formatter:

```cs
builder.Register<MediaTypeFormatter>(c => new UserMediaFormatter())
       .PropertiesAutowired()
       .InstancePerApiControllerType(typeof(UsersController));
```